# Connnecting to MariaDB Docker app using SQLalchemy or mysql gives ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2:3306' (60)

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I am trying to connect to a MariaDB app that I am running on Docker:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306  --name mdb -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password123! -d mariadb:latest
```

Tutorial [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/get-started-with-mariadb-using-docker-in-3-steps/).
The `bid-address` line in `etc/mysql/my.conf` is:

```
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

I've got the IP using:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mdb
```

So the Python code is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:Password123!@172.17.0.3:3306/mdb")
engine.connect()
```

Howevery I've got an operational error from SQLAlchemy and if I try:

```
mysql -h 172.17.0.3 -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
```

I've got:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2:3306' (60)
```

I've lost several hours without finding the solution.

Comment: `#bind-address=0.0.0.0` is a comment.

Comment: use a compose file that runs MariaDB and your app in the same network (but different containers). Then use the container name of mariadb as the host to connect. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77656685/connecting-to-mariadb-in-an-adjacent-container-on-synology-container-manager)

Comment: @GeorgRichter yes I know, but it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from this [comment](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/#comment_5464):

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
```

Instead of retrieving the IP using:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mdb
```